# how many threads are created in this code?

Tags: java, multithreading

`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)` creates 5 threads in the pool, and then in the loop another 100 threads are created. Is this understanding right? Then the 5 threads in the pool will execute each thread in the queue of 100 worker thread.

so in total there are 105 threads created? I had thought only 5 threads are created, but each `Runnable` is also a thread.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    Runnable worker = new WorkerThread("" + i);
    executor.execute(worker);
}
executor.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5) creates 5 threads in the pool, and then in the loop another 100 threads are created. Is this understanding right? Then the 5 threads in the pool will execute each thread in the queue of 100 worker thread.

This is not correct. The fixed-size thread pool executor will create 5 worker threads. Your 100 `Runnable`s are all added to a queue that these 5 threads are pulling from. So only 5 of your `Runnable`s are executing at any given time. There are 5 threads (plus the main thread, and possibly the EDT if you're using Swing, and of course any other unrelated threads that you've explicitly created).

> I had thought only 5 threads are created, but each Runnable is also a thread.

A `Runnable` is not a thread. A `Runnable`, as its name implies, is just something that can be run. In the case of the fixed-size thread pool, it is being run by one of the threads in the pool. From the documentation for [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) (emphasis mine):

> The Runnable interface should be implemented by any class whose instances are intended to be executed **by** a thread.

I believe the source of your confusion may be that your `Runnable`s are innapropriately named `WorkerThread`, even though they are not threads. Additionally, you may be confused by the fact that `Thread` also *implements* `Runnable`. In fact, this literally means that a `Thread` is a `Runnable`, not that a `Runnable` is a `Thread` -- and a `Thread` isn't even a thread until it's started.

Comment: The WokerThread is doing its real job inside executed by one of the 5 threads. If I want to keep a total of how many tasks are done by the 5 threads, how should I do?

Comment: @CongminMin For that you would have to maintain a count somewhere and have each task increment the count when it's done. There are many ways to implement that; all would involve passing an instance of some object that maintains a count to the `WorkerThread` constructors (or setting via some other method before putting the tasks in the pool). Essentially you have to have them call some "callback" method when they're finished that increments a counter somewhere. The executor itself does not provide a way to determine the number of tasks executed.

Answer (score 2):

A `Runnable` is not a running thread. Neither is a `Callable` nor a `Thread` for that matter.

A thread is only created at the JVM level when you `.start()` a `Thread` (which will `.run()` a `Runnable` or `.call()` a `Callable`); until then, they are just normal, regular objects.

As you use an `Executor`, it is the executor which will manage your `Runnable`s or `Callable`s and start "real" threads when it can do so.

Comment: So only 5 threads in total? A runnable is not a real thread.

Comment: Yes, that's it; there are other threads created by the JVM itself though, which you don't have control over (the thread running `main()` is one such thread).

Comment: Calling `run()` does not create a thread! Calling `start()` does. Please update the post.

Comment: @Sourabh yes, sorry; edited

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse the `Thread` class with a thread. Java uses the `Thread` class to spawn threads, but it's not necessarily a 1-to-1 mapping.

In your code, it seems your `WorkerThread` class is a sub class of `Thread`. However, `Thread` also implements `Runnable` and that's how your `ExecutorService` is using it. It just invokes its `run()` method **within one of the 5 threads that it started.**

> how many threads are created in this code?

All the threads started by the `ExecutorService`.

Answer (score 0):

A Runnable is just an `interface` like any other `interface`. Also `Thread` is just a class not a separate thread. An actual thread is not created until you call the `start()` method on Thread class.

Answer (score 0):

"Number of threads in pool will be fixed. If requests come more than the number of threads, they will wait in queue. If a thread dies or terminated, a new thread will be created." [More here](http://www.concretepage.com/java/newfixedthreadpool_java)

In this case, only maximum number of 5 threads would be exist.